# Same language code transformation in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am looking for minimal example on how to read a source code snippet, parse it and transform it back to the same language. Answer in any language is accepted -
 java/python/C#/whatever.

An example use case would be to enforce naming convention for variables - all variables should be prefixed with type where possible, e.g. if it currently states: `public int foo;` it would be transformed to: `public int iFoo;`

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, and ask a question when you get stuck?

Comment: @BartKiers any starting points/? I've seen a lot of examples parsing, but not emitting code back

Comment: With AST generated from the parser, emitting the code is something you should do yourself, and that's why no example emphasizes on that. In your case, the transformation is rather simple, so I don't think you even need someone else to guide you.

Comment: Here is a hint: don't emit. Use the parse tree to figure out which tokens require modification and then modify a copy of the original source text. Every token contains line and column information. Easy enough to figure out stream location as well.